# SMS is not geting in aws SNS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have trying to publish sms from AWS SNS console. It show a success result. But the message is not geting.
Every requests were noted as failure in the console

The response when i publish text message :
SMS message published to phone number +91XXXXXXXXXX successfully.
Message "ID": e3d2bc39-2792-5b2e-adcc-e4733a800795

Comment: Did you activate **Delivery status logging** for the SMS messages? See: [Viewing Amazon CloudWatch metrics and logs for SMS deliveries - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html) It often has to do with the Sender ID not being permitted.

Comment: I have did it, But it's not still send the message

Comment: Please edit your question to include the log output.

Comment: SMS message published to phone number +91XXXXXXXXXX successfully.
Message "ID": e3d2bc39-2792-5b2e-adcc-e4733a800795

Comment: Note that iam publishing the text message from the AWS SNS console. Not with any programing languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and found I need to generate a support ticket to use SNS SMS.
Below is link for generating supporting ticket, explain your use case for SNS SMS

[SNS support ticket link](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/cases#/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-sns-text-messaging)

Answer (score 0):

You can activate **Delivery status logging**.

From [Viewing Amazon CloudWatch metrics and logs for SMS deliveries - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html):

> - On the **Text messaging (SMS)** page, in the **Text messaging preferences** section, choose **Edit**.
> - On the Edit text messaging preferences page, in the **Delivery status logging section**, do the following:
>
>   - Sample rate: 100%
>   - Service role: **Create a new service role** (or choose an existing one if it is there)

You can then send an SMS direct from the **Text message (SMS)** page. It will show a **Delivery Statistics** graph to indicate success/failure.

Also, for each message, there will be a log entry in **Amazon CloudWatch Logs** (go to CloudWatch / Logs / then choose the SNS log). It will look similar to this:

```json
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "xxx",
        "timestamp": "2020-12-09 08:40:19.536"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "phoneCarrier": "Optus Mobile Pty Ltd",
        "mnc": 2,
        "numberOfMessageParts": 1,
        "destination": "+61455555555",
        "priceInUSD": 0.03809,
        "smsType": "Promotional",
        "mcc": 505,
        "providerResponse": "Message has been accepted by phone carrier",
        "dwellTimeMs": 524,
        "dwellTimeMsUntilDeviceAck": 2453
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

This log will give you the most detail of whether an SMS was sent to the phone carrier, so that you can determine where it might be failing.